# .Click handler for child menu items

Tags: wpf, vb.net, drop-down-menu, visual-studio-2012, event-handling

Ok so this should be a basic thing, but I'm having a very difficult time figuring it out.

I'm making a WPF window in visual basic express 2012, using vb.net. I have a Menu added to the window with "File, Edit, etc..." My question is how do I add event handlers to the child menu items?

Lets say I want to add .Click event handler to the "Open" menuitem, which is  under "File" in the menu. How do I go about adding the handler in my code? Basically I've figured out how to add events to the Parent menu items, but not the child items.

Comment: Post the relevant XAML and code.